# JQuery slideshow code not functional with more than one slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on coding a slideshow code, which works if you have one slide show running, however, I wanted multiple. The code selects the active class, which is successfully done for two slide shows, and removes and adds the class, which it again successfully does, however, it cannot select the next slide once it loops once.

My previous code looked like this:

```
 setInterval(function(){
var $currentSlide = $('.active');
var $nextSlide = $currentSlide.next();
if ($nextSlide.length === 0){
  $nextSlide = $('.jumbotron').first();
}
$currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
$nextSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
```

}, 9000);

I attempted to use an each function, however, it does not seem to be working at all:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('.slideshow').each(function(){
  var $currentSlide = $(this).find('.active');
  var $nextSlide = $currentSlide.next();
  if ($nextSlide.length === 0){
    $nextSlide = $(this).firstChild();
  }
  $currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
  $nextSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');

});
}, 1000);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Taplar yes, each slideshow is in a div with the class '.slideshow'

Comment: Quick glance, you probably want your interval inside your each, not outside.

Comment: @Taplar you are right, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? Your code was fine except `$nextSlide = $(this).firstChild();` which gave an error. Just changed that to `$nextSlide = $this.children().first();`

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.slideshow').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $currentSlide = $this.find('.active');
    var $nextSlide = $currentSlide.next();
    if ($nextSlide.length === 0) {
      $nextSlide = $this.children().first();
    }
    $currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
    $nextSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');

  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="active">Slide 1</div>
  <div>Slide 2</div>
</div>

<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="active">Slide 3</div>
  <div>Slide 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, I understand what happened, your code is very readable, thank you so much for your quick help!

Comment: Np. Glad it helped.